# How to return Current Object in a Static function in PHP

Tags: php, oop, static

I neet access to current object in a static method.

Code:

```
protected static $name;

public static function name($modulename)
{
    self::$name = $modulename;
}

public function __call($name, $arguments)
{

    $me = new test(self::$name);
    return $me->$name($arguments);
}
```

I want to be able to call method log in Log class. Like this

`echo Mods::name("Log")->log("test")`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want a Singleton pattern:

http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1304-how-use-singleton-design-pattern.html

Employ log as a singleton and have Mods::name call Log::getInstance();

Comment: Yep i fixed it 
 {
        self::$name = $modulename;
        return new self;
    }